# Unable to show a text box after checking value of other using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to hide the second input box when page loads and show it if the value in first box is more than 0. Also I want to do it by using IDs only. Below is the code I am using, pls help me with mistake I am making in this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Q500b").hide();
            $("#Q500a_2").on('keyup', function(){
                alert("hi");
                if ($("#Q500a_2").val() > 0 && !isNaN("#Q500a_2"))
                    $("#Q500b").show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id='Q500a_2'>
    <input type="text" id='Q500b'>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare values not an object itself

try this

```
$("#Q500b").hide();
    $("#Q500a_2").on('keyup',function(){
        alert("hi");
        if(this.value>0 && !isNaN(this.value)) // Change here
            $("#Q500b").show();
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5FA5Y/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this ***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4At6w/)***

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Q500b").hide();
    $("#Q500a_2").on('keyup',function(){
        //alert("hi");
        if($(this).val() > 0 && !isNaN($(this).val()))
            $("#Q500b").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Q500b").hide();
$("#Q500a_2").on('keyup',function(){

    if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 0)
        $("#Q500b").show();
 });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/377G6/9/)

Answer (score 1):

The key problem is with isNaN:

```
$("#Q500b").hide();
    $("#Q500a_2").on('keyup',function(){
        alert("hi");
        if($("#Q500a_2").val()>0 && !isNaN($("#Q500a_2").val()))
            $("#Q500b").show();
    });
```

You can better write like this:

```
$("#Q500b").hide();
    $("#Q500a_2").on('keyup',function(){
        alert("hi");
        if(this.value>0 && !isNaN(this.value))
            $("#Q500b").show();
    });
```